# Map over slices

Tags: julia

Julia's `map` and comprehension syntax make it easy to map over all elements of a multidimensional array.

Is there a similar support for mapping over *slices* of an array?

As a silly example, given a 3x3x100 matrix, I might want to map over all 100 3x3x_ slices. I might, say, derive the determinant of each 3x3 slice, and end up with a 1x1x100 array of determinants.

Comment: Look at `mapslices`. For your example, `size(A)==(3,3,100)`, then something like `mapslices(det,A,(1,2))` would do.

Comment: That's just what I'm after, thank you. Would you like to make it in to an answer? I can otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `mapslices`. For the question suggest an example with `size(A)==(3,3,100)`. Calculating the 100 determinantst of 3x3 matrices can be done with: `mapslices(det,A,(1,2))`.

Note the resulting matrix is still 3 dimensional, and `squeeze` can be used to get rid of the size 1 dimensions. In the example:

```
squeeze(mapslices(det,A,(1,2)),(1,2))
```

Comment: That `squeeze` is great – it (very nicely) errors if the squeezed dimension doesn't have size 1. It'd be even more super compact if `mapslice` had a way to indicate a dimension should also be sqeezed… but that's very easy to build.